# Convert timestamp to mysql friendly format in python

Tags: python, datetime

I got "timestamp": "2018-10-28T12:49:00.816Z" from a API response. How can I convert 2018-10-28T12:49:00.816Z to %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S format.I tried datetime.strptime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is suprisingly easy using dateutil

```
import dateutil

dateutil.parser.parse("2018-10-28T12:49:00.816Z")
```

output:

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 28, 12, 49, 0, 816000, tzinfo=tzlocal())
```

or directly to your format:

```
dateutil.parser.parse("2018-10-28T12:49:00.816Z").strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

output:

```
 '2018-10-28 12:49:00'
```